# Discrete date values for x-axis in seaborn.objects plot

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn, seaborn-0.12.x

I am trying to prepare a bar plot using `seaborn.objects` with time series data where the x-axis ticks and labels are only on the dates that really appear in the data.

```py
import pandas as pd
import seaborn.objects as so
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'date': pd.to_datetime(['2022-01-01', '2022-02-01']), 'val': [10,20,]})
so.Plot(df1, x='date', y='val').add(so.Bar())
```

The result is the following graph with a tick mark at 2022-01-15. Going to three entries in the dataframe solves the issue, but how would I do it in the presented case.

Adding `.scale(x=so.Nominal())` or `.scale(x=so.Temporal())` does not help.

As a bonus, how would I format the x-axis ticks as "Jan 2022", "Feb 2022" etc.?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert your `date` column as string:

```
(so.Plot(df1.assign(date=df1['date'].dt.strftime('%b %Y')), x='date', y='val')
   .add(so.Bar()).show())

# Or, as suggested by @mwaskom:
so.Plot(x=df1['date'].dt.strftime('%b %Y'), y=df1['val']).add(so.Bar()).show()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: You don't need to assign to the dataframe you can also just pass the transformed vector.

Comment: @mwaskom. Thanks for the suggestion. I updated my answer and give you the credits.